# консольный калькулятор на java

Tags: java, калькулятор

как сделать что бы при вводе в консоли:

```
 java -jar calculator.jar 3 + 7
```

сразу выдавал ответ а не требовал запуска программы

листинг моего калькулятора.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculator {


    private static Scanner read;

    public static void main (String[] args){

        read = new Scanner(System.in);

        double first;
        double second;
        String operator;

        System.out.print(">> ");

        first = read.nextDouble();
        operator = read.next();
        second = read.nextDouble();

        if (operator.equals("*")){
            System.out.println("= " + (first * second));
        }
        if (operator.equals("/")){
            System.out.println("= " + (first / second));
        }
        if (operator.equals("+")){
            System.out.println("= " + (first + second));
        }
        if (operator.equals("-")){
            System.out.println("= " + (first - second));
        }
    } 
}
```

**Обновление**

С подсказки @Nofate, вот такой костыль получился в итоге. Единственное в консоли строку надо вводить без пробелов.

> java -jar calculator.jar 2+5

```
public class calculator {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        String s = args[0];
        char [] ch = s.toCharArray();
        String str1 = "";
        String str2 = "";
        String operator = "";
        char charTmp = ' ';
        int count = 0;
        int countFirsDigit = 0;
        int countSecondDigit= 0;
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;

        while (count < ch.length - 1){
            char c = ch[countFirsDigit];

            if(Character.isDigit(c)){//проверка является ли символ числом
                String strTmp = Character.toString(c);//преобразование char в String
                str1 = str1.concat(strTmp);//склеивание последовательности символов
                x = Double.parseDouble(str1);//преобразование строки чисел в double
                countFirsDigit++;//счетчик первого числа
                count++;//общий счетчик
                countSecondDigit++;//счетчик второго числа

            } else {
                countSecondDigit++;
                count = countSecondDigit;

                charTmp = c;//определяем оператор
                operator = Character.toString(charTmp);

                char c2 = ch[countSecondDigit];

                if(Character.isDigit(c2)){
                    String strTmp = Character.toString(c2);
                    str2 = str2.concat(strTmp);
                    y = Double.parseDouble(str2);
                }
            }
        }
        if (operator.equals("*")){
            System.out.println("= " + (x * y));
        }
        if (operator.equals("/")){
            System.out.println("= " + (x / y));
        }
        if (operator.equals("+")){
            System.out.println("= " + (x + y));
        }
        if (operator.equals("-")){
            System.out.println("= " + (x - y));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Массив `args` в методе `main(...)` содержит параметры командной строки, передаваемые программе при запуске.

Все что вам нужно - взять их оттуда по порядку и преобразовать к нужным типам.

```
first = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
operator = args[1];
second = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Единственное, что не срабатывает команда "*". Подскажите что почитать на данную тему. Спапсибо

Comment: Да, с `*` будут проблемы - это спецсимвол интерпретатора командной строки. Можете попробовать передавать все выражение одним параметром, взяв его в кавычки `java -jar calculator.jar "3 + 7"`, потом вытаскивать его из `args[0]` и разбивать на части самостоятельно.